# Binding datetime-local to controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime

in my angular controller I've defined the followings attributes for my **datetime-local** inputs:

```
vm.startDate = new Date(
    currentdate.getFullYear(),
    currentdate.getMonth(),
    currentdate.getDate(),
    9, 00, 00, 00);

vm.endDate =new Date(
    currentdate.getFullYear(),
    currentdate.getMonth(),
    currentdate.getDate(),
    12, 00, 00, 00);
```

When I start the application, all works fine. The Problem is that when I post this datetime to my controller, the time is wrong. Instead of binding `09:00` and `12:00`, it's binding `07:00` and `10:00`.

What is the problem?

**EDIT:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

I could solve the problem by using **myproperty.ToLocalTime()**

Comment: You should post the code in your MVC controller. Also, make sure that both your client and server are in the same TimeZone.

Comment: @Nasreddine it's UTC both....client and server... no matter what...it's alway saving two hours less

Answer (score 0):

I would put my bet that's an time zone issue, try with UTC as this is the default on the C# part IIRC.:

```
vm.startDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), 9, 00, 00, 00);
vm.endDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), 12, 00, 00, 00);
```

Comment: That is what I was assuming, but not, I just gave it a try and still not working! start date in my MVC controller is still 7:00 !!!!

Comment: and what is in the `Kind` property of the `DateTime` in the controller?

Comment: The type of the property is **DateTime**

Comment: yes, but `DateTime` has a `Kind` property, what is the value of that property in your MVC controller?